# AngularJS Updating Variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, global-variables

I have a global variable and I am assigning a JSON to the global variable on click. However, even when I am not clicking, the global variable is also getting updated.

```
$scope.save = function() { // method called on click
    DataBasket.users = $scope.usersPermissions; // Actually DataBasket is a factory, updating global variable
}
```

I am also manipulating the value of `$scope.usersPermissions` on other clicks. But I don't want it to be updated to the global variable.

How can I solve this?

Comment: very difficult to understand the issue with so little information, please add more details, if possible create a plunk.

Comment: @Rabi After reading it like 5 times I came to the conclusion that what the OP wants is to have a copy of an object in a variable, rather than having the object itself in there. But I agree, I'm still not sure if that is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Josep Ur conclusion is correct. That is what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want is `DataBasket.users` to be a copy of `$scope.usersPermissions`. Try doing this:

```
$scope.save = function() {
    DataBasket.users = angular.copy($scope.usersPermissions);
}
```

Otherwise `DataBasket.users` will reference the same object as `$scope.usersPermissions` and whenenever you change one, the other will change too, because actually they will be the same object.

Comment: @ErmaIsabel you will have to share the rest of the code or it won't be possible to help you more than that. Also, it woud be great if you could set up a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) or an [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so that we can see and try what's wrong with it. Thanks!